# css popup screen animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a popup screen that triggers from clicking a button that utilizes an ActionListener inside Javascript. The animation is basically a horizontal line that expands left to right, once the horizontal line reaches its full length it will expand upwards and downwards to create a popup box. I tried using css webkit animations which are called by javascript but it seems to only make the vertical animation and then the horizontal line vanishes as well as completely ignoring the vertical expansion.

```js
init();
function init(){

    document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById("popup-animation").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("popup-animation").style.WebkitAnimation = 
        "popup-horizontal-line 3s, popup-vertical-expansion 2s 3s";
    });


}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

#popup-animation{
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 30%;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}


@-webkit-keyframes popup-horizontal-line{

  0%{
    width: 0;
  }

  100%{
    width: 40%;
  }

}

@-webkit-keyframes popup-vertical-expansion{

  0%{
    height: 0;
  }

  100%{
    height: 40%;

  }  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Popup Animation</title>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="Btn">Click</button>
<div id = popup-animation>content</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make that an executable snippet using the `<>` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `animation-fill-mode` of `forwards` to both of those animations

Here's one that works in all browsers, using classes rather than "inline" style :p

```js
init();
function init(){

    document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById("popup-animation").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("popup-animation").classList.add('doanim');
    });


}
```

```css
#popup-animation{
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.doanim {
  animation: popup-horizontal-line    3s, popup-vertical-expansion 2s 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
}

@keyframes popup-horizontal-line{

  0%{
    width: 0;
  }

  100%{
    width: 40%;
  }

}

@keyframes popup-vertical-expansion{

  0%{
    height: 2px;
  }

  100%{
    height: 40px;

  }  
}
```

```html
<button id="Btn">Click</button>
<div id = popup-animation>content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the "forwards" keyword in order for the element to keep the styles reached at the end of the animation

Also, get rid of the browser prefix, it's totally unnecessary.  And you might want to add an overflow:hidden to the popup, so the content doesn't show while drawing the horizontal line.

```js
init();
function init(){

    document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById("popup-animation").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("popup-animation").style.animation = 
        "popup-horizontal-line 3s forwards, popup-vertical-expansion 2s 3s forwards";
    });


}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

#popup-animation{
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 30%;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  overflow:hidden;
}


@keyframes popup-horizontal-line{

  0%{
    width: 0;
  }

  100%{
    width: 40%;
  }

}

@keyframes popup-vertical-expansion{

  0%{
    height: 0;
  }

  100%{
    height: 40%;

  }  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Popup Animation</title>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="Btn">Click</button>
<div id ="popup-animation">content</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```